# Passing value through URL and using the value to select SQL row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have this code:

```
 <a href="printable.php?job_numb=<?=$job_numb;?>"
target="new" style="color: #666 !important">
<p><?php echo $job_numb;?></p></a>
```

Which passes the `$job_numb` variable to the URL page. The page picks up the `$job_numb` and does this:

```
 <?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['job_numb'] ) ){
    $job_numb = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'job_numb', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    }
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "xxxxx";
 $password = "xxxxx";
 $dbname = "jobs_users";

 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs_canjobs WHERE job_numb = $job_numb";
     $job_name = $_GET['job_name'];
     $comments = $_GET['comments'];
     $due_date = $_GET['due_date'];
     $attachment1 = $_GET['attachment1'];
     $requestor = $_GET['requestor'];
     $req_email = $_GET['req_email'];
     $Property = $_GET['Property'];
     $assignee = $_GET['assignee'];
     $assign_email = $_GET['assign_email'];
     $AE = $_GET['AE'];
 $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 ?>
```

Which then SHOULD check if $job_numb = job_numb then load these variables. However, it is not showing anything.

I HAD all of the variables passing through the `<a href` but then special characters were mucking up the security and giving a `406 error`. I believe this is probably a more secure option, but I am not getting something right.

Am I missing a step? Thank you.

Comment: You never execute the SQL statement

Comment: The one that parses the job_numb?

Comment: or this: `$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($results);` in the end?

Comment: Are you sure your variable is passed along? <?=$job_numb;?> is not valid in recent PHP versions

Comment: this" `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Another thing, why you assign `$job_numb = $_GET['job_numb'];` after you assign it to `$sql` variable?

Comment: @jdog the variable `$job_numb` seems to be the ONLY one that gets passed along

Comment: @Eric that is my bad. It's a cut and paste error.

Comment: You need to use a prepared statement to do this correctly and to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Also, I am not sure about what is causing the 406 error, but would implementing a $_POST (form) method rather than $_GET (url) do the trick?

Comment: @kojow7 the 406 was caused by special characters passing through the URL. I wanted to eliminate any of that by JUST passing the `$job_numb` variable and matching it on the back end.

Comment: @SeanRawles, yeah, since the POST method sends the data in a separate data stream rather than as a URL I was thinking that POST might allow the special characters. However, I agree, it is much safer and cleaner to pull the data from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs_canjobs WHERE job_numb = $job_numb";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
     $job_name = $row['job_name'];
     $comments = $row['comments'];
     $due_date = $row['due_date'];
     $attachment1 = $row['attachment1'];
     $requestor = $row['requestor'];
     $req_email = $row['req_email'];
     $Property = $row['Property'];
     $assignee = $row['assignee'];
     $assign_email = $row['assign_email'];
     $AE = $row['AE'];
}else{
     echo 'no records found';
}
```

Comment: this was it! Incorrect order and a missing IF. Thank you @NiloVelez

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

"Return Values ¶

Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE."

So you need to use mysql_fetch_array() or similar on the result to get data